# PDF report showing boxes instead of fonts when deployed to azure using Rotitiva in asp.net core

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created a MVC ASP.net core project. For pdf reports I am using Rototiva. When working on the local environment everything works fine but when deploying to the azure the report showing boxes.

I have gone through the previous post and tried to fix the issue based on the recommendation but nothing helps, so writing this post if some one have gone through the issue and found the solution.

Note: I am not  using free website of Azure.
[image]

This is the code and I modified the style based on Jason solution:
Controller Partial code:
[image]
[image]

View:
[image]

**Update--Issue is resolved**

This issue is resolved. My application hosting plan was D1 (shared)on Azure. I had to scale up the app plan and get the B1. Once on B1 I am not seeing anymore issue. But it costing me $40 extra per month to resolve the issue. I would look for some other option to create the report rather than Rotative

Comment: Can you show us the code about this page ? Or you can tell us what language is the text on the page, Chinese or Korean, etc.?

Comment: I use [jerateep's sample code](https://github.com/jerateep/GenPDF) and deploy it, it works fine, you can check [my pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI4qJ.png).

Comment: Hi Jason,  it is English . These report consist of Strings and Dates.

Comment: You have also seen my screenshots. If possible, can you provide the sample code, which is just for this garbled page. Please protect your personal information.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have updated my post with the code. I did try your style, again it is working on local fine but when deployed to the Azure I am seeing boxes.

Comment: [I have tried the code you provided and the problem cannot be reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68oRS.png). It is recommended to raise a support ticket on portal and let Microsoft engineers assist.

Comment: This issue is resolved.  I application hosting plan was D1 (shared). I had to scale up the app plan and get the B1.  Once on B1 I am not seeing anymore issue. But it costing me $40 extra per month to resolve the issue. I would look for some other option to create the report rather than Rotativa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application was hosting on Auzre using plan D1 (shared)on Azure. I had to scale up the app plan and get the B1. Once on B1 I am not seeing anymore issue. But it costing me $40 extra per month to resolve the issue. I would look for some other option to create the report rather than Rotative